# PySpark reading multiple files while creating new column containing existing column name

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I would like to read *n* csv files using pyspark. The csv have the same schema but with different columns names.

[image]

While reading those files I would like to create an additional column 'pipeline' that contains a substring of first column name.

How can I implement this?

```
 df = spark.read.format("csv") \
                .option("header", True) \
                .load(path + "*.csv")
                .withColumn("pipeline",
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = spark.read.format("csv") \
                .option("header", "false") \
                .load(path + "*.csv")
                .toDF('header_1')
                .withColumn("pipeline", lit(path))
```

Comment: Please add description or comment to your answer

Comment: The column header is not known, how do I retrieve 'header_1'?